# merging the equations of the line

Tags: polynomials, coordinate-systems

I have two equations for plotting the line. How can I merge them to get a single equation?
$$\begin{align}y&=7.515x^3 - 10.229x^2 +5.05x, \,\, x \leq 0.5\\
y&=0.185x + 0.815, \,\,                  0.5<x\leq1\end{align}$$

I actually require equation of a line passing through following points:
$(0,0),\,(0.2,0.7), \,(0.5,0.9),\,(1,1)$

But connecting lines between these points should be straight, especially between the last two points.

Comment: Your first function is a cubic curve, not a line...

Comment: yes, first is curve and second is straight line. is it possible to merge them and get a single equation which satisfies all the points??

Comment: This is badly posed. You have no freedom (parameters) to merge them together at $x=0.5$. For the cubic curve you get $y(0.5)
 = 0.907125$ and for the line you get $y(0.5) = 0.9075$.

Comment: Also the cubic curve does not go through the second point; $y(0.2) = 0.66096$

Comment: You can get *three* equations, one for a straight line joining the first two points, another for a straight line joining the second and third points, and a third equation for a straight line joining the last two points. Will that do for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find a polynomial curve that passing through these 4 points, this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Example_1) could be helpful. The fitting curve can be calculated by Lagrange Interpolation. In your case, I find the curve below by using Mathematica's function `InterpolatingPolynomial` that could satisfy your conditions.

$$y = (x-1) ((5.08333 (x-0.5)-1.6) x+1)+1 = 5.08333 x^3-9.225 x^2+5.14167 x$$

Answer (score 0):

We can find such polynomial (not a line) as follows:

$$y=y_1\left(\frac{x-x_2}{x_1-x_2}\cdot\frac{x-x_3}{x_1-x_3}\cdot\frac{x-x_4}{x_1-x_4}\right)+y_2\left(\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot\frac{x-x_3}{x_2-x_3}\cdot\frac{x-x_4}{x_2-x_4}\right)+y_3\left(\frac{x-x_1}{x_3-x_1}\cdot\frac{x-x_2}{x_3-x_2}\cdot\frac{x-x_4}{x_3-x_4}\right)+y_4\left(\frac{x-x_1}{x_4-x_1}\cdot\frac{x-x_2}{x_4-x_2}\cdot\frac{x-x_3}{x_4-x_3}\right)$$ where $x_1=0,y_1=0,x_2=0.2,y_2=0.7,x_3=0.5,y_3=0.9,x_4=1,y_4=1$.

Substituting these values in the above expression of $y$, we get:

$$y=0\left(\frac{x-0.2}{0-0.2}\cdot\frac{x-0.5}{0-0.5}\cdot\frac{x-1}{0-1}\right)+0.7\left(\frac{x-0}{0.2-0}\cdot\frac{x-0.5}{0.2-0.5}\cdot\frac{x-1}{0.2-1}\right)+0.9\left(\frac{x-0}{0.5-0}\cdot\frac{x-0.2}{0.5-0.2}\cdot\frac{x-1}{0.5-1}\right)+1\left(\frac{x-0}{1-0}\cdot\frac{x-0.2}{1-0.2}\cdot\frac{x-0.5}{1-0.5}\right)$$

Simplifying this expression, we get:

$$y=\frac{175}{12}x(x-0.5)(x-1)-12x(x-0.2)(x-1)+\frac{5}{2}x(x-0.2)(x-0.5)$$

This expression can be further simplified as convenient to you.

Here is the graph of this curve where is passes through the four given points.

[image]

By the way, this is Lagrange's polynomial interpolation method which Erdos Yi mentioned in his answer.

I know this question was asked in June, but I liked to share the solution, you or other may need to know how to do Lagrange's polynomial interpolation. Hope this helps.